# Welch test for ANOVA or ANOVA test with unequal variance?

Tags: anova

I'm not sure if stack-overflow is the best forum for this, but anyway,

`Scipy` implements `ANOVA` using stats.f_oneway, which assumes equal variances. It says in the docs that if the variances are unequal, one could consider the `Kruskal-Wallis` test instead.

However, what I want is Welch's ANOVA. Scipy has a Welch t-test, but of course this doesn't work if I have more than two groups.

What I find interesting is that Scipy used to have stats.oneway which allowed for an equal variance setting. However, it has been deprecated.

Is there an easy way to implement Welch's ANOVA in Python?

Answer (score 0):

The [pingouin library](https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.welch_anova.html) has pg.welch_anova which can be used to implement Welch's ANOVA in python.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).